# Binding two array elements into one

Tags: javascript, loops, each

I have a issue which is hurting my head cant think how to do it. I have the following feed.

```
[{
    "title": "thumb_36cr8350.jpg",
    "url": "http://example.com/s3images/thumb_36cr8350.jpg",
}, {
    "title": "large_36cr8352.jpg",
    "url": "http://example.com/s3images/large_36cr8350.jpg",

}, {
    "title": "thumb_36cr8358.jpg",
    "url": "http://example.com/s3images/thumb_36cr8358.jpg",
}, {
    "title": "large_36cr8360_a.jpg",
    "url": "http://example.com/s3images/large_36cr8358.jpg",

}]
```

which i am looping through

```
var thumb = "<ul id='thumbs'>";
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
    var params = baseName(item.title).split("_");
    if (params[0] === 'thumb') {
        thumb += '<li><a class="group1" href="{this need to be the large thumb}"><img src="' + item.url + '" width="75" height="75"/></a></li>';
    }
});
thumb += "</ul>";
$('.conatiner').html('<div id="wrap">' + thumb + '</div>');

function baseName(str) {
    var base = new String(str).substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if (base.lastIndexOf(".") != -1)
        base = base.substring(0, base.lastIndexOf("."));
    return base;
}
```

I need to somehow push the large pic into the href of the list for the Lightbox effect.

Cannot for the life of me think how to do this.

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if this is what you're looking for:

```
var thumb = "<ul id='thumbs'>";
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
    var params = baseName(item.title).split("_");
    if (params[0] === 'thumb') {
        thumb += '<li><a class="group1" href="#{url}"><img src="' + item.url + '" width="75" height="75"/></a></li>';
    } else {
        thumb = thumb.replace("#{url}", item.url);
    }
});
thumb += "</ul>";
$('.conatiner').html('<div id="wrap">' + thumb + '</div>');

function baseName(str) {
    var base = new String(str).substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if (base.lastIndexOf(".") != -1)
        base = base.substring(0, base.lastIndexOf("."));
    return base;
}
```

Comment: It depends on order in which items are passed in response... Just a note.

Comment: Yes, I did it with the array the OP provided in mind (to keep it simple)

Comment: the output i am getting from console.log(thumb); is 12 <ul id='thumbs'>

Comment: Uhm, that's weird, it's working for me with the response you provided, look: http://jsfiddle.net/VZGts/1/

Comment: I guess it could be the response, try `console.log(response)`, and see what you get :)

Comment: Thankyou i managed to get it to work by swapping it around instead of thumb using large works nice now :0